# HTML: Paragraph text doesn't stack up to rows. (All the text is in one line and out of paragraph)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap grid system and you can see the problem right here.

[image]

The text which is supposed to be in the center keeps outgoing from the center to right side as you can see...

```
<div class="row mt-2">
   <div class="col-3"></div>
   <div class="col-6">
      <div class="text-left">
         <p class="d-0">
            <span id="issuer_msg" style="white-space: pre-line">{{msg.message}}</span>
            <br>
         </p>
         <div class="text-center">
            <small class="text-primary font-weight-normal">{{msg.sent_time}}</small>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix  the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from your inline styles where you used "white-space:pre-line"

Try using "white-space:pre-wrap" instead

Comment: Still same issue, nothing changed.

Comment: DzJTC maybe you should apply some styles to the element, break the word that overflows the container.

Comment: @Fritzdultimate for example what styling?

Comment: @DzITC word-break:break-all you can read more on that. This will break only words.

Comment: That's good, since it helps, do upvote the comment to rank top.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from your small tags. Wrap paragraph around it.

Comment: Hey, I wrapped it with <p> but nothing happened, still the same issue.

Comment: Put your message in p tag only and remove the span tag completely